# Can first law of thermodynamics be explained in terms of entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can first law of thermodynamics be explained in terms of entropy? I am bit confused. I need help.

Comment: No, the first law of thermodynamics is about energy conservation, entropy is not a conserved quantity, thus any attempt at relating the two would be in vain.

Answer (score 4):

Energy and entropy are different things. The first law of Thermodynamics deals with energy. It is a statement about conservation of energy on macroscopic systems. It states that if a system has its energy changed, then it is because there was one exchange of energy between the system and its surroundings.

The part of the exchange in energy due to changes in macroscopic degrees of freedom is called work while the part of the exchange in energy due to the microscopic and not measure degrees of freedom is called heat. With this we write $\Delta U = Q + W$.

The second law is not a statement about conservation of energy. The second law is a statement about the natural direction in which processes take place. If you let a cup of hot coffee alone the coffee will cool instead of heat. If you get two bodies in contact with different temperatures, the flow of heat is from the hotter to the colder and not the other way around.

The second law is an attempt to explain those situations. Explain why there's a natural direction for changes on macroscopic systems and why we do not observe the changes in the other way around. It is not talking about conservation of anything.

In truth, the second law had many formulations before being rephrased in terms of entropy. One of the possible ways to formulate it is the Clausius formulation:

> No process is possible on which heat is transfered to a colder body to a warmer body with no work involved.

This captures the idea that heat has a natural direction to flow, something which is not captured by the first law.

Lately it was found out that all of this is due to entropy. It was found out that it can all be summarized as follows:

> If a macroscopic isolated system undergoes a thermodynamic process then the entropy of the system always increases, that is, $\Delta S\geq 0$.

In that sense the second law can't explain the first law because they are written with different things in mind. The first law is a statement of conservation of energy, looking at the change in energy of a system and relating to the exchanges in energy between the system and its surroundings while the second law is a statement about the natural direction of a thermodynamic process.